# I've messed up again. I'm such a failure

Tags: language, anagram

My brother always says that I can never do anything right. It looks like I've proven his point for him once again... I tried to create some [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) pronunciation guides, but I managed to put the letters in the wrong order and now they don't make any sense. Augh!

Can you help me put the letters back in the correct order? Do you think my brother is right?

> 1. diːɹɪŋ
> 2. ɜːdbɪ
> 3. kʰɪdʒbɹæm
> 4. lɛstgaʊtʃə
> 5. mædhɜː
> 6. ɹɪntʃwiːg
> 7. sɛltʃeɪtə
> 8. stɔːwɛtʃə
> 9. θaʊmpaɪl
> 10. wɪkwɔː
> 11. wɪntʃɔː

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The words seem to be

> ɹiːdɪŋ *Reading*
>  dɜːbɪ   *Derby*
>  kʰæmbɹɪdʒ *Cambridge*
>  glaʊtʃɛstə *Gloucester* (suggested by [WAF](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/53367/waf))
>  dɜːhæm *Durham*
>  gɹiːnwɪtʃ *Greenwich*
>  leɪtʃɛstə *Leicester*
>  wɔːtʃɛstə *Worcester* (suggested by [WAF](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/53367/waf))
>  plaɪmaʊθ *Plymouth*
>  wɔːwɪk *Warwick*
>  nɔːwɪtʃ *Norwich*

and they are all

> Cities in the United Kingdom containing universities

Can you do anything right?

> All of the names are mispronounced, as [M. Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm) points out.
>  The correct pronunciations are (all taken from Wikipedia, but adjusted to match the non-rhotic British accent given in the mispronunciations):
>  ɹɛdɪŋ
>  dɑːbɪ
>  kʰeɪmbrɪdʒ
>  ɡlɒstə
>  dʌɹəm
>  ɡɹɛnɪtʃ
>  lɛstə
>  wʊstə
>  plɪməθ
>  wɒɹɪk
>  nɒɹɪdʒ

Comment: Aaargh, didn't get the last one. (I think the two question-marked ones have one t too many and one s too few.) And I think the gimmick is that they're all /mɪsprəˈnaʊnst/.

Comment: I think the question mark ones should just be rot13(tynʊgʃɛfgə) and rot13(jɔːgʃɛfgə) without the rot13(fuver). Not the greatest application for my first use of rot13.

Comment: @MOehm I'm not British, so it seems that I missed the joke. I'll correct the answer with your insight

Comment: Neither am I, but the given examples are somewhat notorious. (And WAF is certainly right; I thought that these two referred to the counties and thus would end with /ʃə/.)

Comment: How did you solve this... I was two hours into a Python program, and decided there were much better uses of my time :-p

Comment: @Parseltongue The first two were easy because there were only a few ways to reassemble the sounds as a word (though I did get *birdy* on my first try for the second). Once I realized these were place names, I used [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_universities_in_the_United_Kingdom) to locate the harder ones.

Comment: Gotcha -- I naively went to the brute force approach first.  A good puzzle would be words that, when the IPA pronunciation is mixed up, can actually yield multiple real words.